# How to see number of connection in zookeeper

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I want to see number of connection in zookeeper runing , as m running through lily , so it is giving  exception but want to check number of connection in zookeeper.

http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperStarted.html

Comment: seen by cons | nc 127.0.0.1 2183 | wc -l

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [ZooKeeper Admin guide](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkCommands) has details on how to do this. Look at the "stat" command. You might also use [JMX](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperJMX.html) depending on your monitoring sophistication.

PS: 3.1.2 is pretty old, you should upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

please input:

```
echo cons | nc localhost 2181
```